# Orbeon Forms application - migration from 3.8 to 4.9

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am migrating orbeon forms application from 3.8 to 4.9 version. All of my forms where written with Eclipse/OxygenXML - not by built-in form designer. I have read all migration notes, and everything works fine but each *.xform page contains strange section (Reloading form) at the begginning. I can't find any error in orbeon.log file or other..

"Reloading form

This form has to be reloaded. This most likely happened because your session has expired, which might take to the login page. (If you think that you shouldn't see this message and that the problem persists, please contact support.)

OK
$xforms-template-label$$xforms-template-help$$xforms-template-hint$$xforms-template-label$$xforms-template-help$$xforms-template-hint$"

Thanks for any suggestion what is wrong.

Regards, 
Grzegorz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be having this problem because of [this](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/styling#TOC-Orbeon-Forms-4.0):

> Bootstrap, XForms engine, Form Runner and Form Builder rules are now contained within an enclosing `.orbeon` CSS class. This ensures that the Orbeon CSS rules only apply within an element with that class. It also makes Orbeon CSS rules a bit stronger than before. You might have to update your custom CSS to take this into account.

What you are seeing in your browser is supposed to be there in the DOM, but it should be hidden by CSS. To check if this indeed explains the problem you're seeing, I recommend you add an `orbeon` class on your `<body>` element (e.g. `<body class="orbeon">`).

Comment: @GrzegorzEwicz Excellent, I'm glad that solved the issue. And you were not the first one to hit this ;). We're still glad we did that namespacing, even if it created a bit of pain for people upgrading from 3.9.